# size figures according to tabular column width

Tags: tables, floats, includegraphics

I'm putting together a multi-panel figure which will also eventually get some row and column labels. In order to do this, I think the best approach for the skeleton of the structure is to `\includegraphics` inside a tabular environment.

At the moment I have something like this (consider this a 'pseudo-MWE'):

```
\begin{figure}[p]
  \begin{tabular}{cccc}
    \includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{image1.pdf} &%
    \includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{image2.pdf} &%
    \includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{image3.pdf} &%
    \includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{image4.pdf} \\%
  \end{tabular}
\end{figure}
```

I'm wondering if there is some way to express the overall dimensions (i.e. the table width) in the tabular environment, at present it spans the `\textwidth` as I'd like it to; but also be able to express the individual image dimensions in terms of the *cell width* without specifying it explicitly as above?

Ideally I'd end up with each column of the table equating to roughly 0.25*`\textwidth`, and then the images to fit themselves accordingly, as if I was calling something like:

```
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{myimage.pdf}...
```

Comment: The table width changes according to the contents of the table, so usually you don't know the width of the table until it's complete. If you use `p` column types, though, you can refer to the width of the column as `\linewidth`. Sorry, I don't know a better approach with `tabular`.

Comment: OK, thanks, that's got me to a workable solution for now, I just specify 4 `p` columns which are `0.25\textwidth`, and then `\linewidth` works as you say. I'll be interested to see if there is a 'proper' or more elegant solution though.

Comment: The expression `\begin{tabular}{\textwidth}{cccc}` can't be correct, as the `tabular` environment takes 1 argument, not 2. Did you mean to write `\begin{tabular}{cccc}`?

Comment: Yes, sorry I just noticed that myself, I'll edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `tabularx`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[p]
  \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XXXX}
    \includegraphics{example-image} &
    \includegraphics{example-image} &
    \includegraphics{example-image} &
    \includegraphics{example-image} \\
  \end{tabularx}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Interesting, never seen `setkeys` before. What's going on in that line?

Comment: It sets the key `width` for the group (ie. environment `figure`) to a default value. See the documentation of package `graphicx` (grfguide.pdf).

Comment: As a bonus this solved an extra problem I was having. `tabular` didn't like me trying to put text in the cells above the figures for some reason (messing up cell length calculation I figure?), but `tabularx` has no such qualms. Thanks!